# Multiprocessing Python Pool.map issue cannot concatenate str with int objects TypeError

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, queue, pool

I am not able to get to a my function by calling pool.map(func, iterable) syntax. My iterable is nothing but list of numbers on each line (no other comma seprated values like :

```
LINE01AA1
LINE02AA1
LINE03AA1
LINE04AA1
LINE01AB1
LINE02AB1
LINE03AB1
```

The code gives an error which is like Error which is thrown : ***raise self._value TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects***   code is pasted below :

```py
if __name__ == "__main__": 

    # print ID of current process 
    print("ID of process running main program: {}".format(os.getpid())) 

    # print name of main thread 
    print("Main thread name: {}".format('Main')) 

   #Start Time 
    start = time.clock();

    q = Queue()
    filename = 'test.csv'#load file
    load_file(filename)
    print("Total Lines Loaded : " + str(len(my_var)))

    p = Pool(2)
    p.map(getData, my_var)
    p.close()
    p.join()end = time.clock();
    print "The time was {}".format(end - start)

def load_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as datafile:
       for line in datafile:
            my_var.append(line.strip())

def getData(number):
    print(number)
    proc_name = current_process().name
    proc = os.getpid()
    print("Process:" + proc_name + " PID: " + proc + "Data : " + number)

    #set Data 
    data['r1[]'] = number[:6]
    data['r2'] = number[6:]
    #print data
    response = requests.post('https://somewebsite/post.php', headers=headers, data=data, proxies=proxies)
    print response.text
```

Comment: What's is the stack trace of the error? And didn't you search for this first? This is a very common error.

Comment: Is `number` a number? `"Data : " + number` looks suspicious.

Comment: Try `"Data : " + str(number)`

Comment: `print("Process: {} PID: {} Data : {}".format(proc_name, proc, number)` - fixed this for you. PID (`proc` variable) is int for sure, number might be a number (but we can't see that) - using string formatting is universal

Answer (score 0):

Was really a petty overlook, just encapsulated variables in str() in print statements !